# Can't find img pythonanywhere django

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

I put the project on both heroku and pythonanywhere and on both platforms there is a problem with the fact that it does not find exactly images.

Path to static at pythonanywhere

[image]

Staic settings in project:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

Comment: I think `STATICFILES_DIR` is used for additional static files and not the core static files and it only works if `collectstatic` is used.  Try something like this: `STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`

Comment: run command `python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: i already ran collectstatic? it didn't help

Comment: The best way to debug this would be to work through it step by step.  Identify the URL of a file that is not loading up, say `http://www.yoursite.com/static/something/image.jpg`.  Then look in the directory `/home/milleniax/matoff/static/something/image.jpg` and check if the file is there.  One thing to keep an eye out for is the case of the characters.  `Image.jpg` is not the same as `image.jpg` or `image.JPG`.

Answer (score 0):

In [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#static-root):

> The *absolute path* to the directory where collectstatic will collect static files for deployment.

(emphasis mine)

So yes, you need to make sure you run the management command and change your setting to have an absolute path.
Why does it work on localhost? Because `DEBUG` ignores `STATIC_ROOT`.